# Reference two classes in each other

Tags: python, class

I have two classes, one is designed to contain the other

```py
class Thing:
    def __init__(self, parent: Box):
        self.parent = parent
        parent.add_to_box(self)

class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = []

    def add_to_box(self, item: Thing):
        self.children.append(item)
```

However I can't reference the class types (`parent: Box` and `item: Thing`) within each other, only either one or the other.

How can I reference both class types within each other? And otherwise what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use strings:

```
class Box:
    def add_to_box(self, item: "Thing"):
        ...
```